# WireMock mTLS does not work wiremock.org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to test the Apache HttpClient v4.5 using mTLS with WireMock v2.27.2. I followed [this page](https://wiremock.org/docs/https/#requiring-client-certificates).
Unluckily I get the following errors:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty client certificate chain
```

and

```
wiremock.org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
```

I tested the Apache HttpClient mTLS with a Spring boot application setup with mTLS and there it works. Maybe something in WireMock is not working. This is how the WireMock code looks like:

```
 mutualTLSServer= new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig()
          .httpsPort(8090)
          .needClientAuth(true)
          .keystorePath(pathKeystore)
          .keystorePassword("password")
          .keyManagerPassword("password")
          .trustStorePath(pathTruststore)
          .trustStoreType("jks")
          .trustStorePassword("password"));

      mutualTLSServer.start();
      configureFor("https", "localhost", mutualTLSServer.httpsPort());

 stubFor(get(urlMatching("/get"))
 .willReturn(aResponse().withBody(expectedResponse).withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "close")));
```

Does anyone know where the problem could be?

Comment: v2.27.2 is very old so I suggest trying again with WireMock 3.1.0. If this still doesn't work then it might help to post the steps you took to build the trust store you're using.